# WordPress / jQuery: Getting conditional logic to work on select field in form

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Trying to get a checkout form I have in WooCommerce (WordPress) to display certain fields based on the user selection in a select dropdown menu. All the ID's are different based on the name of the selection. Can't seem to make it work at all. Code is basically like this:

HTML:

```
<select name="select-menu" id="select-menu" class="select " required="required" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="Select One --&gt;" >Select One --&gt;</option>
  <option value="select one" >First Selection</option>
  <option value="select two" >Second Selection</option>
  <option value="select three" >Second Selection</option>
</select>

<p class="form-row " id="input1" data-priority="10"><label></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="input-one" id="input-one" placeholder="" value=""></span></p>
<p class="form-row " id="inputtwo" data-priority="20"><label></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="input-two" id="input-two" placeholder="" value=""></span></p>
<p class="form-row " id="thirdinput" data-priority="30"><label></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="input-three" id="input-three" placeholder="" value=""></span></p>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#select-menu').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'select 1') {
      jQuery('#input1').show('fast'); }
  else if (jQuery(this).val() == 'select 2') {
      jQuery('#inputtwo').show('fast'); }
  else if (jQuery(this).val() == 'select 3') {
      jQuery('#thirdinput').show('visible'); }
  else if (jQuery(this).val() == 0) {
     jQuery('#input1', '#inputtwo', '#thirdinput').hide('visible'); }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: None of those values "match". Why not use the index of the Options?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
jQuery('#select-menu').change(function() {
  var i = $("option:selected", this).index();
  console.log(i);
  jQuery("p[id^='input']").hide();
  if (i > 0) {
    jQuery('#input' + i).show('fast');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-menu" id="select-menu" class="select " required="required" data-placeholder="">
  <option value="Select One --&gt;">Select One --&gt;</option>
  <option value="select one">First Selection</option>
  <option value="select two">Second Selection</option>
  <option value="select three">Second Selection</option>
</select>

<p class="form-row " id="input1" data-priority="10"><label></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="input-one" id="input-one" placeholder="" value=""></span></p>
<p class="form-row " id="input2" data-priority="20"><label></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="input-two" id="input-two" placeholder="" value=""></span></p>
<p class="form-row " id="input3" data-priority="30"><label></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="input-three" id="input-three" placeholder="" value=""></span></p>
```

This uses a relative association based on the Index of the Options.

Comment: Not going to work here. You see, In reality, all the ID's in a p tag are going to have drastically different names based on the actual name in the label. So I'm just using input1, input2 and so on as placeholders.

Comment: @AdamBell you didn't indicate that in your post or example.

Comment: I didn't think I had to. I can redo it to make it more obvious.